# thread lambda expression in Kotlin

Tags: java, multithreading, kotlin, java-threads

Sample code:

```
fun main() {
   thread(name = "Worker Thread") {
        for (i in 1..5) {
            println(Thread.currentThread().name)
        }
    }
    println(Thread.currentThread().name)
}
```

Decompiled bytecode for the above sample:

```
public final class PracKt {
   public static final void main() {
      ThreadsKt.thread$default(false, false, (ClassLoader)null, "Worker Thread", 0, (Function0)null.INSTANCE, 23, (Object)null);
      Thread var10000 = Thread.currentThread();
      Intrinsics.checkNotNullExpressionValue(var10000, "Thread.currentThread()");
      String var0 = var10000.getName();
      boolean var1 = false;
      System.out.println(var0);
   }

   // $FF: synthetic method
   public static void main(String[] var0) {
      main();
   }
}
```

Code works fine but I can't understand in decompiled code how thread gets executed without calling `start()` method. If I try to call `thread.start()` in sample code, **IllegalThreadStateException** is thrown.

Where is `start()` method is getting called if not shown in decompiled code?

Comment: In decompiled code it's inside `thread$default`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it goes from [Kotlin docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.concurrent/thread.html). When you're using method `thread`, created thread is started by default.

```
fun thread(
    start: Boolean = true,
    isDaemon: Boolean = false,
    contextClassLoader: ClassLoader? = null,
    name: String? = null,
    priority: Int = -1,
    block: () -> Unit
): Thread
```

To start it explicitly, you should set `start` flag to `false`.